# Scipy nquad integration with arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, arguments

I tried to integrate in python using nquad. The problem is that when I try to pass extra arguments to the function which is being integrated in nquad, it wants to pass those parameters to bounds instead to function. I searched the internet and found that it was a bug in `scipy.__version__ < 0.18.0`, and was fixed then, but I have got version 1.1.0 and the problem persists. What should I do? The simplified example is below

```
>>> from scipy.integrate import nquad
>>> ranges0 = lambda x: [x, 2 * x]
>>> ranges = [ranges0, [1, 2]]
>>> func = lambda x0, x1, t0, t1: x0 + x1 + t0 + t1
>>> nquad(func, ranges, args=(1,2))

>>> TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some digging in the documentation for [nquad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html) and I have found this excerpt:

> If an element of ranges is a callable, then it will be called with all of the integration arguments available, as well as any parametric arguments. e.g. if func = f(x0, x1, x2, t0, t1), then ranges[0] may be defined as either (a, b) or else as (a, b) = range0(x1, x2, t0, t1).

In other words, when defining a `func` with 4 parameters you must define your `range` to take exactly `4-pos` parameters. In other words, since your `ranges0` is in the first place in the range list, it will be passed `4-1=3` parameters, if you put it in the next place in the list it will be passed `4-2=2` parameters. The same is true for all further places in the array. It stays at 2 because it is called with:

> all of the integration arguments available

Here the problem is not related to scipy but it more relating to a logical error on your part.

In summary, a function in the range list can **never** accept one and only one argument when there are 2 time variables.

Comment: Wow, my bad, thank you very much for pointing that out, it works perfectly now. :)